# Is there a way to make a folder in /tmp while using google cloud functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I needed to create two folders within `/tmp` folder in Google Cloud functions. I am using a library which requires the files to be in that format (they can't just all be in `/tmp`).

I tried this - `os.makedirs('tmp/test')` but that gave the following error:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'tmp'
Detailed stack trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 315, in check_or_load_user_function
_function_handler.load_user_function()
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 190, in load_user_function
spec.loader.exec_module(main_module)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/user_code/main.py", line 3, in <module>
os.makedirs('tmp/test')
File "/env/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'tmp'
```

Any way I can solve this?

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 766 /tmp`

Comment: You might want to prefix `tmp` with `/` to ensure it tries to create the subdirectory under the root `/tmp` and not under the current directory. So `os.makedirs('/tmp/test') `.

Comment: Hi @Shawn did you give it a try following Frank's comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `os.makedirs('tmp/test')` will attempt to create a directory at `/user_code/tmp/test`, which is not writeable.

You'll want to use a leading slash to ensure that you're creating the directory at `/tmp/test` instead, which is the only writeable part of the filesystem.